# How to search for text in a whole Eclipse project instead of file by file

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse allows you to search its code using Edit->Find/Replace. This allows you to search only one file at a time. Is it possible to search for a text in a whole Eclipse project instead of searching file by file

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can navigate to

```
Search >> File
```

When in you can then specify your string and a working set. Set the working set to your project folder. Depending on how picky you want to be you can set the file name patterns too. I have not tried but I am assuming you can do `*.*` to search everything under the sun.

You can use the below image as a reference (I used Eclipse - Galileo). I searched for the string "System" and got results for my class file and my interface file. Once you search all occurances will show up in a search tab (normally docked on the bottom of the screen).

Each instance can be double-clicked to take you to that specific occurance.

[image]

Comment: This helped me as I was using the wrong tab first, thinking "Java Search" would be good enough.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut to search files in Eclipse project.